# How do we cache http response with koa?

Tags: node.js, koa

Sometimes response returned from the server hasn't been changed, so is there a way to cached the response? i'm using Koa v2

Comment: https://github.com/koajs/static-cache    or    https://github.com/koajs/cash  are not so helpful ?